# Creating buffer based on polyline without line end caps and without dissolving the created polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, dissolve

I have a projected line layer (Shapefile) in QGIS. For every line segment I want to create a polygon without line end caps. The resulting polygone should not be dissolved to a single one.

I tried fTools buffering tool. This can create a buffer without dissolving, but its not possible to define the line end caps.

I tried also v.buffer of GRASS. This can create a buffer with defined line ends, but I cannot disable the dissolving.

Is there a possibility to have both: not dissolved and without caps at line end? The result should be a Shapefile with polygons (buffer) for every line segment.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of what you have in mind?

Comment: Why not write some python to loop through the line segments and run v.buffer on each seperately?

Answer (score 6):

With `GRASS v.buffer` press `Iterate over this layer` button.

[image]

Below (RHS) figure shows buffers, a buffer polygon layer per each polyline feature, without dissolved parts. Then merge output buffers. (`Vector | Data Management Tools`)

[image]

Comment: slightly ridiculous that you have to make a seperate layer for each buffer/line segment. This is simply not feasible for complex geometries

Comment: the graphic above is a bit outdated, but the tool is now simply called v.buffer    I believe v.buffer.distance capability was merged into the single user tool.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that this might be what you are after:

[image]

If so, I think you have to first break up your polylines into lines, e.g. using the 'Explode lines' processing tool.

Then, applying `v.buffer` as you mention above might leed to success.

**update**

What I just saw is that the 'Explode lines' tool shoots a little over the target, because it explodes each polyline into segments with only start- and endpoint and nothing in between...